# How can I close a specific window using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, window

I use Selenium WebDriver. I open the first page then open the second page - perform some action and go back to first page. Before I want to close the second page I use the command `driver.close();`, but it closes the first page instead of the second. How can I make Selenium to close a specific window?

Part of code

```
String HandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).click();
 for (String twohandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(twohandle);
    }       
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("001")).click();
 driver.close();
```

Comment: does the click happen in the right (second) window?

Comment: The code is not very readable. You don't use the stored `handleBefore`, then you `switchTo()` to all windows in a loop. I guess that the last `switchTo` gets you to the first window instead of the second. I recommend you to start over, [read the docs once again](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) and read the javadocs of [`switchTo()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#window%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: You have to take the window handles to switch between parent and child window.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
    String base = driver.getWindowHandle();

    Set <String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();

    set.remove(base);
    assert set.size()==1;

    driver.switchTo().window(set.toArray(new String[0]));

    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(base);
```

This works for me...

Comment: My code works, just something wrong with sequense of closing window

Comment: @Khris A [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is of `java.util` package.

Comment: Franz, I am using intellij and 'driver.switchTo().window(set.toArray(String[0]));' line says 'expression expected' what does that mean?

Comment: just enter the new keyword for the Array declaration, edited my answer accordingly, sry

Answer (score 12):

In Python

```
default_handle = driver.current_window_handle
handles = list(driver.window_handles)
assert len(handles) > 1

handles.remove(default_handle)
assert len(handles) > 0

driver.switch_to_window(handles[0])
# do your stuffs
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(default_handle)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can close a specific window by it's title or identifying a specific unique element of that window..

```
private void SwitchTabandClose()
{
    Set <String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

    for (String handle: windows)
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        System.out.println("switched to "+driver.getTitle()+"  Window");
        String pagetitle = driver.getTitle();
        if(pagetitle.equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ Title"))
        {
            driver.close();
            System.out.println("Closed the  '"+pagetitle+"' Tab now ...");
        }
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ramnarayan's solution works great. Modified it a bit for reusablity:

```
public static String switchToWindowByTitle(WebDriver driver, String windowTitle) {
  Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
  String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
  for (String handle : handles) {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    if (windowTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.getTitle())) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return currentHandle;
}


// How to use method
String currentHandle = SeleniumUtil.switchToWindowByTitle(driver, WINDOW_TITLE);
driver.close(); // Close WINDOW_TITLE page or do other things
driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle); // Return to current page
```

Answer (score 0):

Following a little the work of the other post, I have done it like this.

```
     public static void changeFocusToWindowByTitle(WebDriver driver, String windowTitle) {
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String windowHandle : handles) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            if (windowTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.getTitle())) {
                logger.debug("Focus has been changed to the window: " + driver.getTitle());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

 public static void closeWindow(WebDriver driver, String windowTitle) {
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); ;
        for (String handle: handles ) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(windowTitle)) {
                logger.debug("Close window: " + windowTitle);
                driver.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```