# How to automatically close firebug tab when launching selenium firefox webdriver with firebug?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have included firebug when launching firefox driver and it works very fine with latest selenium web driver 3.0 but meanwhile it also opens new firebug tab every time when launching browser.

As code says, i have included firebug file and added this extension in created profile. Is there any way to close the firebug tab automatically after launching the browser? If there is no automatic way then i need to use tweak to close window named "Firebug" right?

## Code:

```
File file = new File("./firebug-2.0.17-fx.xpi");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", config.getStringProperty("geckodriver.path"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(file);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449179/how-can-i-close-a-specific-window-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java ?

Comment: I have added in initial comment already that i'm looking for automatic solution but anyhow need to handle via open windows only :) Posting an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "showFirstRunPage" flag to "false" in your porfile.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.showFirstRunPage", false);
```

Here is a link to all firebug preferences you can set.
[Firebug Preferences](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences)

An other solution is to set the "currentVersion" to a big number like this.

```
profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "999");
```

I prefer the first on ;)

Comment: Pretty awesome! Please accept the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for automatically closing Firebug window but i think its not possible so posting an answer to handle opened windows after launching firebox browser with firebug capabilities, unfortunately you need to deal with extra lines of code due to this issue :)

Below solution it works fine, just use it like below:

## Working code:

```
File file = new File("./firebug-2.0.17-fx.xpi");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", config.getStringProperty("geckodriver.path"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(file);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

// Close the firebug window
Thread.sleep(4000); // Firebug window takes time to open it
Set <String> windows = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
String mainwindow = webDriver.getWindowHandle();

for (String handle: windows) {
    webDriver.switchTo().window(handle);
    if (!handle.equals(mainwindow)) {
        webDriver.close();
    }
}
webDriver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
```