# Not able to close tab in chrome browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not able to close tab in chrome browser using JavaScript
last line in below code `js.executeScript("window.close()");` is not working. Can any one please help on the issue?

```
package TestCode;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Chrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Akash\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.facebook.com')");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        js.executeScript("window.close()");

    }

}
```

Comment: Actually this way you can not close other window.. you need to switch that window first by finding all open window as `driver.windowHandles` and then close that window as `driver.close()`.. follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449179/how-can-i-close-a-specific-window-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)..

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493572/closing-all-opened-tabs-except-the-first-tab-main-tab-using-webdriver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By invoking `js.executeScript("window.close()");` you are trying to close the main window, not which you have just opened. To close popup window you need to locate it somehow or save the reference to it in the `JavascriptExecutor` context.

Note, that global variables there [should be preserved](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html):

> Note that local variables will not be available once the script has
>   finished executing, though global variables will persist.

So you could try to do the following:

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("popup_window = window.open('https://www.facebook.com')");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    js.executeScript("popup_window.close()");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `getWindowHandles()` and `getWindowHandle()`

```
String parentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Pass a window handle to the other window
 for(String childWindow: driver.getWindowHandles()){
if(!childWindow.equals(parentWindow))
{
System.out.println("child");

//switch to child window
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
//Your operations
 driver.close();

}
}
System.out.println("Come to parent window");

//switch to Parent window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```